# jQuery on click handler not activated on asp.net component

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, loader

I'm working on an  C#/Asp app with some jQuery.

I'd like a specific function called every time a click is made on a component with a class like "loadingInProgress". However, the code below doesn't seem to work and I am not sure why. I have tried with the ID, with CssClass instead of class and using `.click()` instead of `.on('click', ...)` to no avail.

Here is the button code

```
    <asp:Button ID="btn_Rechercher" Text="Rechercher" runat="server"  class="loadingInProgress"
                   OnClick="btn_Rechercher_Click" />
```

And my .Js.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.loadingInProgress').on('click', function (e){

    /* OVERLAY ON AJAX    */
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        displayOverlayInProgress();
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        removeOverlayInProgress();
    });          
  });
    });
     function displayOverlayInProgress() {
     $('.overlay').show();
     $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
    }

    function removeOverlayInProgress() {
    $('.overlay').hide();
    $('body').css('cursor', 'auto');

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems you haven't tried `OnClientClick`.

```
asp:Button ID="btn_Rechercher" Text="Rechercher" runat="server"  class="loadingInProgress" 
OnClick="btn_Rechercher_Click" 
OnClientClick="loadingInProgress"/>


function loadingInProggress() {

    displayOverlayInProgress(); // don't wait for ajaxStart


    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        removeOverlayInProgress();
    });   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It seems like your solution doesn't freeze the web page at the begining of the process but only when the server answers. I need to freeze the web page all along the process

Comment: @BarryF I think calling `displayOverlayInProgress()` function directly would satisfy your need. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

Html:

```
   <asp:Button ID="btn_Rechercher" Text="Rechercher" runat="server"  class="loadingInProgress"
                       OnClick="btn_Rechercher_Click" />
```

Jquery:

```
 $("#btn_Rechercher").click(function () {

 $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        displayOverlayInProgress();
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        removeOverlayInProgress();
    });  

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Rechercher" Text="Rechercher" runat="server"  CssClass="loadingInProgress"
               OnClick="btn_Rechercher_Click" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have tried this before without sucess

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should not run `.ajaxStart` and `.ajaxComplete` each time you click the button.
You shoud implement those two callbacks on `.ready` but then in `.click` event you should just call `.ajax`, `.load`, `.get` or any other method which will start the request